# SignalR server updates vs. client interest in a subset of updates

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

In many of the examples I've seen, such as the StockTicker app, it's assumed that all clients would be interested in the updates to all stock prices...

I'm trying to determine a best practice for when a client only cares about a subset of updates...

Would I:

1. broadcast all updates to all clients, and let the clients determine
   "if they care" in the client method?
2. register with each client connection the "items of
   interest" and maintain a client connection table somewhere,
   broadcasting iteratively to all clients which have expressed that
   interest?
3. Create a SignalR Group for every stock (for example), and
   register clients to each particular stock-group "of interest" and
   broadcast only to a particular group during an update of the related
   stock?
4. something else I'm missing...

In an effort to make this question less subjective, what are the pitfalls of each of the above scenarios (rather than "which do you like better?")?

Thanks gang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Would I:"

1. "broadcast all updates to all clients, and let the clients determine "if they care" in the client method?"

   This solution is probably the simplest to implement and reason about. Unfortunately, this solution also creates the most network traffic. It also may be considered insecure in some scenarios where the messages being sent are sensitive and should be hidden from some clients.
2. "register with each client connection the "items of interest" and maintain a client connection table somewhere, broadcasting iteratively to all clients which have expressed that interest?"

   This seems fairly similar to SignalR groups in concept, but broadcast iteratively to individual clients typically isn't as efficient as broadcasting to a group. This is primarily because SignalR only has to publish one message to its bus per group broadcast.

   Still, you might want to maintain a "client connection table" containing the "items of interest" for each client even if you end up using the built-in SignalR groups functionality. SignalR only allows you to add/remove clients to/from a group and broadcast to a group, so if you want to find out who's currently in a group you are going to have to track that yourself.

   If you do maintain your own table, you can avoid sending messages you know no client is currently interested in. You could also automatically resubscribe clients to their items of interest when they leave and come back.
3. "Create a SignalR Group for every stock (for example), and register clients to each particular stock-group "of interest" and broadcast only to a particular group during an update of the related stock?"

   This would be my choice. Groups align naturally to "items of interest". Given your scenario, I don't see much of a downside, particularly if you also maintain your own "client connection table" as well.
4. "something else I'm missing..."

   I think you covered the three basic options.

Comment: If I go the groups route, it's my understanding that if a group doesn't exist, SignalR can send to it without exception (which is fine with me).  Is that correct?  Is there an upper bound to the number of groups that can exist simultaneously?